# ERR_CONNCTION_TIME_OUT on all hosted websites

Tags: php, wordpress, server, web-hosting

I have domain from namecheap.com and they hosted on my dedicated server with bluehost.com. suddenly since last 2 weeks im facing an issue. on all my domain that i have from namecheap.com hosted on bluehost after browing for few mins gets ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT error and then immediately page reloads automatically. Even on the Cpanel login page of these domains we get the same issue. Though we have some domains registered with bluehost it self and hosted on the same blue host server we dont get this error on those domain. We have contact bluehost they said all is fine from their end, we contacted namecheap.com they said all is good from their end. Now i am stuck what to check and where to check, we have reinstalled the website scripts disabled all the plugins but we still getting this error, it is not all the time when we try to browse website after two three pages we get this error and then its gone then after 2 3 pages it comes again and then gone.
Any sort of suggestions or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, an error `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` occurs when you have intermittent Internet connectivity. I believe you won't face the same problem in other ISP. To fix that, you can try flushing the DNS of your local computer by issuing command `ipconfig /flushdns`from command prompt. In addition, edit local computer hosts file located at Computer `C:\ Windows\ System32\ Drivers\ etc\Hosts`, and look for entry like `0.0.0.0 example.com`. Remove that entry, save the file and restart your computer.